# For socket accept(), is client address still good when it fails?

Tags: c, sockets

Recently, my server reports lots of accept error "too many open files". I use the following code for accept.

```
socklen_t sl;
struct sockaddr_in client_address;
int c_sock = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address, &sl);
if (c_sock < 0)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "accept(): %s", strerror(errno));
...
```

I want to modify the code so that when it happens again I can capture the client address to know where it comes from. For that purpose, I wonder when accept returns -1 (for this particular error), does client address still contains valid information? I check man page and it doesn't mention that. So, if not where to get client address when accept fails due to too many open files.

Comment: Side notes: `socket` overrides `socket()` function name, `sl` must be initialized with `sizeof(client_address)`.

Comment: No, of course it doesn’t. There is no client, so no client address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Upon failure the only output that is well defined is the return value and `errno`.